# Vauxhall Zafira rear lights not working

Tags: electrical, lights, vauxhall, zafira

Hi all I have a 2006 Vauxhall Zafira and have a problem with my rear passenger side lights, the indicator is working fine but no brake light or evening lights I have changed all the bulbs and still the problem persists. Im assuming its not a fuse as the driver side rear lights work as they should. Please can anyone advices me on what to check.
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Because stop / tail lights are so important, manufacturers will occasionally split the circuit so that they have a fuse for each side of the car.  That way, if the fuse blows, you don't loose all lightning so I wouldn't simply assume that it isn't the fuse.

With a bit of research, it points to fuse 7 being responsible for the right hand side tail light and fuse 25 being responsible for the left.  The indicator circuit is on a separate fuse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same on my Zafira. It is usually a incorrect fitted light switch. When the switch is replaced it can happen that the bottom half of the terminals are getting pushed in. That cancel out the whole of the rear lights and the beam adjusters.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix:

1. park car
2. turn on right indicator with ignition off
3. then turn on left indicator then return to centre position all with
   ignition off.

All fixed.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure how that solves the issue? What is the theory behind how it would even start to fix the issue? Could you better explain what you're doing and what you're talking about?

Comment: duno just worked....

Comment: Is there a reference you used to get the information for why you did this in the first place?

Comment: no.. just sitting in car in dark... then just put indicator on right with no key... then left.. for out top look.. it was working on right addo then tested all on